# Python Regex - extracting the sentence that contains asterisk

Tags: regex, regex-negation

```
test_string: '**Amount** : $25k  **Name** : James **Excess** : None Returned \n **In Suit?**  Y **Venue** : SF **Insurance** : N/A \n **FTSA** : None listed'

import re
regex = r"(?:^|[^.?*,!-]*(?<=[.?\s*,!-]))(n/a)(?=[\s.?*!,-])[^.?*,!-]*[.?*,!-]"

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

I tried to extract '**Insurance** : N/A' from the string. But my above code doesn't work. How can I make it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The regex to extract `**Insurance** : N/A` is `\*\*Insurance\*\* : N/A`. What are you *really* trying to extract?

Comment: Another more generalized regex to match anything `**word** : N/A` which might be closer to your intention is [`\*\*\w+\*\* : (n\/a)`](https://regex101.com/r/cjPyyg/1). Careful that you escape characters like `*` and `/` because they have special meaning in regex. However it looks like you're regex is supposed to extract something more specified than this, can you expand on your inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: `**In Suit?**  Y` looks out of line. Do you miss a colon there?

Comment: **In Suit?** Y  is by purpose to be in a new line

Answer (score 0):

I would treat the content like a (semi-structured) key-value file format.

You can match the key-value pairs with a regex like this:

```
(\*\*[a-zA-Y ?]+\*\*) : ((?:(?!\*\*).)*)(?= |$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV9Qzn/1/)**

Explanation:

- `(\*\*[a-zA-Y ?]+\*\*)` the key: you may have to adjust the character range
- `:` the kv separator with surrounded by spaces
- `((?:(?!\*\*).)*)` the value is captured with a tempered greedy token: everything but literal `**` followed by `(?= |$)` the end of string `$` or a separating space.
  (?= |$)

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/uR0kOe):

```
import re
regex = r"(\*\*[a-zA-Z ?]+\*\*) : ((?:(?!\*\*).)*)(?= |$)"
test_str = "**Amount** : $25k  **Name** : James **Excess** : None Returned \\n **In Suit?** : Y **Venue** : SF **Insurance** : N/A \\n **FTSA** : None listed"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    if match.group(1) == "**Insurance**":
        print (match.group(2))
```